# Do I need to use exception handling if I use ELMAH?

Tags: asp.net, elmah

Do I need to wrap my code with `try...catch` statements if I use ELMAH?

I have the following code:

```
namespace ElmahTestApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {

                DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("asdasdasd");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

The view shows up (as expected) however the exception does not get logged. Any suggestions? THanks in advance!

Comment: @ SLaks I was trying to cause an expcetion intentionally :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at ErrorSignal. In your case, you'd do something like

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
}
```

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct because you answered my questions. I was wondering if there's an API for using ELMAH? THanks

Comment: For documentation on ELMAH, try the wiki on the official site (http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), and also there are several links to other examples.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your code to handle exceptions gracefully (eg, fallback to something else), you still need `catch` blocks.

Comment: That i understand. However if I wrap my code with a try/catch it doesn't get recorded with ELMAH. I updated my question, please have a look at the code block

Comment: @Dragan look at Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e) if you want to catch them.